# Why do I get a syntax error when I try to convert this model?

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is the script provided by TensorFlow's docs for converting a tf2 model to tflite: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert#cmdline

I only added the path to my SavedModel directory.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Convert the model
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('./exported-models/my_model/saved_model') # path to the SavedModel directory
tflite_model = converter.convert().

# Save the model.
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

I get an error at tflite_model = converter.convert(). am I supposed to add something? If I remove dot (.) then I use to get below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eddie\anaconda3\envs\tf2.3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py", line 196, in toco_convert_protos
    model_str = wrap_toco.wrapped_toco_convert(model_flags_str,
  File "C:\Users\eddie\anaconda3\envs\tf2.3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\wrap_toco.py", line 32, in wrapped_toco_convert
    return _pywrap_toco_api.TocoConvert(
Exception: <unknown>:0: error: loc("Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/input/_0"): requires all operands and results to have compatible element types
<unknown>:0: note: loc("Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/input/_0"): see current operation: %1 = "tf.Identity"(%arg0) {device = ""} : (tensor<1x?x?x3x!tf.quint8>) -> tensor<1x?x?x3xui8>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./converter.py", line 5, in <module>
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
  File "C:\Users\eddie\anaconda3\envs\tf2.3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py", line 1076, in convert
    return super(TFLiteConverterV2, self).convert()
  File "C:\Users\eddie\anaconda3\envs\tf2.3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py", line 899, in convert
    return super(TFLiteFrozenGraphConverterV2,
  File "C:\Users\eddie\anaconda3\envs\tf2.3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py", line 629, in convert
    result = _toco_convert_impl(
  File "C:\Users\eddie\anaconda3\envs\tf2.3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py", line 569, in toco_convert_impl
    data = toco_convert_protos(
  File "C:\Users\eddie\anaconda3\envs\tf2.3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py", line 202, in toco_convert_protos
    raise ConverterError(str(e))
tensorflow.lite.python.convert.ConverterError: <unknown>:0: error: loc("Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/input/_0"): requires all operands and results to have compatible element types
<unknown>:0: note: loc("Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/input/_0"): see current operation: %1 = "tf.Identity"(%arg0) {device = ""} : (tensor<1x?x?x3x!tf.quint8>) -> tensor<1x?x?x3xui8>
```

Comment: Assuming you copy-paste your code, remove the dot ```.``` at the end of the line with the error. otherwise, attach the stack trace of the error please

Comment: Delete the dot at the end of the line.

Comment: Sorry I just updated, removing the . still results in an error

Comment: requires all operands and results to have compatible element types -> this tells me u r trying to convert two different types

Comment: Can you check if the path to the model is correct?

Comment: I fixed by installing tf nightly and adding code from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41877#issuecomment-666404074